# Adjoint equation for the second order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For 
\begin{align}
p_0 (x) \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} + p_1(x) \frac{du}{dx} + p_2(x) u = f(x)
\end{align}

The adjoint equation is 
\begin{align}
v(x)[p_0 (x) \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} + p_1(x) \frac{du}{dx} + p_2(x) u ] 
= \frac{d}{dx} \left( A(x) \frac{du}{dx} + B(x) u \right)
\end{align}
For some $A(x)$ and $B(x)$. 
I want to find the differential equation for $v(x)$.

The equation for $v(x)$ is called adjoint differential equation, how this and original equation is related with?

$i.e$, If we know the solution for $v(x)$ then we also know $u(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  v(x) \left[ p_0 (x) u'' + p_1 (x) u' + p_2(x) u\right] = \frac{d}{dx} ( A(x) u' + Bu)
\end{align}
Find the differential equation for $v(x)$.

equating left and right hand side
\begin{align}
  ( vp_0 - A ) u'' + ( v p_1 - (vp_0)' - B) u' + (vp_2  - B')u=0
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
  vp_0 = A, \quad vp_1 = A'+B,  \quad vp_2 = B'
\end{align}
eliminating $A$, and $B$ we have
\begin{align}
  &(vp_0)'' - (vp_1)' + vp_2=0 \\
  & p_0 v'' + (2p_0'-p_1)v' + (p_0'' - p_1' + p_2)v=0
\end{align}
The differential equation for $v$ is called the adjoint differential equations.
This $v(x)$ is the integration factor for original equation $p_0 u'' + p_1 u' + p_2 u =f$, giving
\begin{align}
  v p_0 u' - (vp_0)' u + vp_1 u = \int v f dx + C
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Very short answer: introducing the so-called inner product 
\begin{equation}
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x) g(x) \text{d}x,
\end{equation}
and introducing the 'operator $L$ which acts on a function $u$ as
\begin{equation}
 L u = p_0(x) u''(x) + p_1(x) u'(x) + p_2(x) u(x),
\end{equation}
we can look at the inner product $\langle L u,v\rangle$ for some function $v(x)$. Now, we can ask ourselves if we can find the so-called *adjoint operator* $L^*$, for which the following holds:
\begin{equation}
\langle L u,v \rangle = \langle u, L^* v \rangle.
\end{equation}
If you write down what this means in terms of the actual form of $L$ and the actual form of the inner product, which is an integral, you see that you can try to apply integration by parts (possibly multiple times) to convert a term in the integral such as $u'' v$ into something like $u v''$.

This is all properly and clearly defined in terms of function spaces, in particular Hilbert spaces. Fore more information, I would advise you search for these terms, in particular in the context of Sturm-Liouville problems.